# Screenshot in C# on Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot, selenium-grid

I am having a strange issue when trying to take a screenshot when running the tests against a selenium grid

```
 public void TakeScreenshot(object methodName)
    {
        try
        {
            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
            var filePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\..\\..\\Screenshots\\" + methodName + ".png";
            ss.SaveAsFile(filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            throw;
        }

    }
```

I have the following method to take a screenshot but when it runs on the gird I get the following failure even if the test has passed.

> System.InvalidOperationException : Session [(null externalkey)] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.

And when i run it locally i get the following

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : A exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:54408/session//screenshot. The status of the exception was ConnectFailure, and the message was: Unable to connect to the remote server

However, for both of these environments, i get the screenshot but this is failing the test.
Does anyone know the best way to take a screenshot in C# for selenium?

---

Update - I have found out this only seems to happen after the test has finished, I placed the exact same code in the [BeforeScenario] and it didn't error so its something that happens at the end of the test...

Comment: it looks like you are trying to take a screenshot on an exception which occurs when the driver is quitting.  You won't be able to take a screenshot once the session is disposed.

Comment: @FlorentB. thanks for your comment and yes it seems the AfterScenario is being called several times which is why taking the screenshot is failing even though the screenshot is above driver.quit. so I commented out the driver.quit and added a number randomizer to the screenshot and ran a test and found it took 11 screenshots!!! which seems to suggest this is being called 11 times!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why this is happening thanks to the comments.

The reason I was getting that error was that there was no Driver, the reason for no driver was due to the [AfterScenario] being called multiple times so the 2nd time it ran there was no driver and therefore the screenshot couldn't be taken.

The reason my after scenario was being called multiple times was because it was in a base class I created which was inherited by each step class.

Once I created a new class and moved the after/before scenarios out into its own separate class then my after scenario was only being called once and the error was gone.